# The title of my submitted arxiv paper is wrong. How to change the title of arxiv paper?

Tags: arxiv

[This](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2104/2104.11017.pdf) is my submitted paper to arxiv. You can see the shown title at the topleft conor is "Author Guidelines for 8", which is not the correct title at all.

[This](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2110/2110.08085.pdf) is my another submitted paper to arxiv. You can see the shown title at the topleft conor is "Sample manuscript showing specifications and style", which is not the correct title.

I do not know the reason. Can anyone tell me why such weird things happen? And how to change them?

Comment: Hi! You can [replace your articles with a new version](https://arxiv.org/help/replace), for which you can change the title.

Comment: @Marvin Hi Marvin, It seems that the 'topleft title' is automatically assigned by the ArXiv system. For instance, [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.11096.pdf) paper's title shown at 'topleft conor' is "1809.11096.pdf". I found most ArXiv papers have such titles (a series of number) at the 'topleft conor'. Some papers have the same title with the real paper like this [one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08318.pdf). Do you know why?

Comment: Assuming you exported from Word, go to File > Info > Properties and set the title there.

Comment: The comment by @GoodDeeds is good, but note that there are several ways of making a PDF from Word, and they might not all deal with the title in the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This comes from the metadata of the PDF file. Since the paper appears to be uploaded to the arXiv as "PDF Only", it presumably is already in the file you uploaded to the arXiv. You can open the PDF in Acrobat Reader, for example, and choose "Properties..." from the file menu. There you can see the metadata stored in the file. It looks like the file was prepared in Word. Once you export it to PDF from there, there may be some options to change it.

Comment: Yes. You can remove all properties and personal information from the PDF metadata.